# How to upload 4GB file to alfresco?

Tags: java, alfresco

Now I use Alfresco 4.0d, I can upload only 2GB file. I want to upload a file which size is more than 4GB. How can I customize to upload 4GB file in Alfresco?

Comment: Did you try anything, e.g. searching the internet for 'alfresco max file size upload'?

Comment: How are you uploading the files? CIFS? WebDAV? CMIS? Share? Explorer? IMAP?

Comment: See https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?t=17602 and other hits from Google

Comment: There's a well known flash issue where the flash uploader cannot handle files over 2GB. I guess some people get around that by using a classic HTML uploader, though I don't yet know how to disable the flash one..

Answer (score 3):

By default you should be able to upload 2GB files into Alfresco.

Alfresco's CMIS interface has a default maximum upload size of 4GB, you can remove this limitation by adding the following `alfresco-global.properties` line [as described in the documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/pra/1/concepts/cmis-config.html):

```
opencmis.maxContentSize=-1
```

What filesystem is alf_data on? If it is FAT32, [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662412) is be the problem.

Comment: Thank Raoul, Yes I try to search in google. Now we change from Alfresco EMS to other framework. Thank for U your answer.